# 4096 MiB SD card in Android Emulator... less than 9MB?

Tags: android-emulator

Every time I attempt to create a new AVD with the latest Android SDK (under Eclipse), I can't actually specify SD Card Sizes greater than 1024 MiB. Any attempt to specify higher numbers gets me always the same message:

"SD Card Size must be at least 9MB"

What gives?

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you enable the SD Card in Hardware properties

Answer (score 1):

[Known issue. Vote for it.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7038)

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem too.

Answer found here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7038

I've also reproduced it with the same setup as Michael.  Here is some additional detail on what sizes are 
considered valid or invalid when generating a new AVD (set to MiB):

0-8: invalid
9-2047: valid
2047-4104: invalid
4105-6143: valid
6144-8200: invalid
8201: valid

=====

For example, I tried 4096MB and it gave the same error.   But when I changed it to 4196M, the avd got created!!!