# Android create avd size on windows command prompt

Tags: android, winapi, windows-xp

I'm starting with Android development and I have no idea what's wrong on the this command line:

`C:\Documents and Settings\Gabriel.Esquivel.android\avd>android create avd -n Ev
o4G -t 9 -c 8000MB -s 480-800 
Valid skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, HVGA (default), WQVGA432, WVGA800, QVGA
Error: '480-800' is not a valid skin name or size (NNNxMMM)`

I am trying to create the following AVDs http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/, but it won't work on from Android SDK Manager. There seems to be bug that throws the following error "SD Card size must be at least 9MB".  So I have decided to try from command prompt as I read on other blog that it will allow me to create AVDs without getting SDs less than 9MB errors.

Now the problem is that it won't take specific dimensions for the skin `-s width-height`

Comment: Why do you want your SD card less than 9MB?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused... the real problem is the following :  I need SD= 8GB (see TutsPlus Specs ) and according to my maths that's iquals 8192MiB, and when I specify that amount on SDK Manager it gives me the "at least 9MB" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `android create avd -n Ev o4G -t 9 -c 8000M`

From what I vaguely recall of reading the source code, you can only create an SD card up to 999MB in size. It's purely a restriction on the length of the string (i.e. 3 digits).

However, you can first create an emulator with a small SD card (say 9MB), then replace it with a larger one created using the [`mksdcard`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#mksdcard) command.

For example, this should replace the 9MB SD card for your above emulator:
`mksdcard 8192MB %USERPROFILE%\.android\avd\Evo4G.avd\sdcard.img`

---

Actually, re-reading your question, I'm not sure whether you were having problems with the SD card size?

If you want *no* SD card, you can simply leave out the `-s` parameter to `android create avd`.

Anyway, for the customised screen size, you want the format `WIDTHxHEIGHT`, e.g. `480x800`.  That's what the error message is telling you (`NNNxMMM`).

But since 480x800 is a standard resolution, you can just use `WVGA800`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't noticed the format NNNxMMM, 
though it won't accept MB, K|M values
<code>android create avd -n Ev o4G-t 9 -c 8000M -s 480x800</code>
Error: SD Card size must be at least 9MB

If I try this
<code>android create avd -n Ev o4G -t 9 -c 8201M -s 480x800</code>
It gets into loop ( not responding ), this seems to be due a known issue http://tinyurl.com/2379mp2

creating AVD with SD equals to 12, 16, 64 (MiB supposedly)works

WROX book recomends you to use 12 MiB for your first AVD, TutsPlus SceenShot of Evo4G configuration says 16M

I'm really confused with these values.

Comment: same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933276/4096-mib-sd-card-in-android-emulator-less-than-9mb

Comment: Ok, so it's a known bug. Good thing I posted a workaround above then! :)

Comment: yeah it seems that´s the only way.. Thank You !!

Comment: Yeah, if you enter 128M, it creates a 128MiB SD card. Am I really no longer the accepted answer? :)